# vim: is there any way to replace a paragraph without using the visual mode?

Tags: vim

when i want to replace a paragraph with a content that I have in the clipboard, I select it first with the visual mode, but... is there any way to replace it without using the visual mode?

For example, I can copy a paragraph without going to the visual mode just using y+i+p.

Comment: You don't want to ask "is there" but "how to" - there are not many thing that are *not* possible with vim ;)

Comment: When you say 'without using the visual mode', do you really really mean that?  Or do you just mean without having to manually select the lines of the paragraph?  Because you could just do vip followed by your clipboard paste.

Comment: +ngm I do what you say (`vipp`) but my mind seems to reject it (and I'm having some trouble internalizing it)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say

```
"_dipP
```

The `"_` selects the [*'black hole register'*](http://www.cs.csubak.edu/docs/vim/motion.html#_) for the deletion so as to preserve contents of registers.

See also [`:help registers`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#registers)

Answer (score 3):

`cip` = change inner paragraph

That will leave you in insert mode, at which point you can use `<c-r>"` to insert contents of the `"` register.

So `cip<c-r>"` to replace the current paragraph with the contents of the `"` register (which will hold your most recent yank).

Comment: There has to be something better than `cip` that does not enters Insert mode.  I use `vipp`, but it uses the visual mode and my mind fights it.  `rip` (replace) changes just one character. =(